# placing of multiple iframe in a html file

Tags: html, iframe

I want to use multiple iframes but on doing  this, I am getting it below each other.

how to align them and place them wherever i want?

Also, how to remove "scrolls" from iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing the scrollbars:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="...">
```

If they're not aligning horizontally maybe they're too wide, or just displayed as block elements, in that case use CSS property *float*